# G Suite SSO, restricted to company accounts, in Python and Flask?

Tags: python, authentication, google-signin, google-identity

Let's say I work for `mycompany.com`. I'm building an internal web app in Flask for accessing some company data. It will not be hosted on Google's App Engine.

At `mycompany`, we use G Suite for email, calendars, etc. I have access to the G Suite Admin Console and can make whatever changes necessary.

What I'm trying to do is to provide Google Authentication in the Flask app, but only for people that work at `mycompany`, that have a `@mycompany.com` email address through the company's G Suite account.

I've spent a good amount of time poking through Google's documentation and I've found [the web authentication example](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) and the [Authenticating Uses with Python](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/authenticate-users) example. I've run both examples. Neither restrict access to `mycompany`'s G Suite accounts.

Do I need to implement that logic myself or does G Suite provide a mechanism to use SSO authentication restricted to company members?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like I need to create a [custom SAML app](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519) and that I can use the [python3-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml) library to accomplish that. There's a demonstration Flask app in the library.